# what is side of any oblique triangle if given length of other two sides and all three angles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangulation

For any oblique triangle, which may be acute or obtuse, if I know length of two sides, and I know all three angles, how can I determine length of unknown side?

All three sides may or may not be equal length.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines

Comment: Got it.  Did I get the answer write?

Answer (score 0):

Using Law of Sines:

missing length c = known length b X sin C / sin B
where A,B,C and triangle's angles, and b is angle opposite B.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the law of sines or the law of cosines. If $ABC$ is a triangle and the only unknown length is the one of $c=AB$, from
$$ \frac{\sin A}{a}=\frac{\sin B}{b}=\frac{\sin C}{c}=\frac{1}{2R} \tag{1}$$
we get $c= b\,\frac{\sin C}{\sin B} = a\,\frac{\sin C}{\sin A}=2R\,\sin C$. We also have:
$$ c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C.\tag{2}$$